# How to add an extra metdata to a field of an object?

Tags: c#, attributes, metadata

I have an abstract class Node that everybody should implement in our office:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public abstract void run();
}
```

The implemented classes should also contain at least one input and one output properties. Please look at the following example:

```
public class LineNode : Node
{
    public Point a;
    public Point b;
    public Line line;
    public override void run()
    {
        line = new Line(a, b);
    }
}
```

In this class `a` and `b` are the inputs and line is the output. Other users can find which one is output by reading the body of `run()` method (It is ridiculous isn't it?). But the main problem is that somewhere in my application I need to know whether a field is an input or output. So I can show the input and output variables graphically. Or throw an exception if somebody tried to assign an output outside of a node or even return an error in compile time. (I do not want use private keyword I need all fields to be public). 
At first I tried to wrap fields in typed `Input<T>` and `Output<T>` classes so it was possible to list all the Output fields of a node using reflection. But everybody complained that it becomes complicated in that way. Because we had to create a simple int property in two lines:

```
Output<int> out = new Output<int>();
out.value = 10;
```

Is it possible to write something like this in c#?

```
public class LineNode : Node
{
    [Input]
    public Point a;
    [Input]
    public Point b;
    [Output]
    public Line output_line;
    public override void run()
    {
        output_line = new Line(a, b);
    }
}
```

So whenever somebody tries to 
I know attributes can only be applied on types not variables but I had something like this in my mind so everybody can enjoy writing a new node
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there are reason you have to use public fields and not properties? With properties, you could use `{ public set; private get; }`  for input and `{ private set; public get; }` for output.

Comment: Because the people who are developing the nodes hate programming  :| I could not convict them to declare private properties or getter and setter! They want something so easy like attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Attributes just like you wrote in the last block of your code. For that, you need to declare the following classes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Input:Attribute
{
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Output:Attribute
{
}
```

Then, you can retrieve the attribute(s) of the field using reflection:

```
var isInput = Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(LineNode).GetField(fieldName), typeof(Input))

var isOutput = Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(LineNode).GetField(fieldName), typeof(Output))
```

Comment: Attributes, please, Not *annotations*!

Comment: I already tried it. But It does not work. when are just able to get the attributes from types. But I tried to apply the attribute to the variables.

Comment: Please explain how exactly it does not work? Attributes can be applied to class fields (like in your example). If you are trying to apply them to local variables inside a function - you are correct, this will not work

Comment: @DenisYarkovoy I tried it and it worked. Thanks. May be I had made mistake before. But do you think this is the best solution? An Does exist any way to return an error in compile time? Thanks

Comment: @a.toraby Personally I think that it is a bad way. Getters and setters are much better (and are meant specifically for such cases), but if you can't use them for whatever reason - go with attributes. What error would you like to return at compile time, not sure I understood?

Comment: I need to return an error for example If somebody tried to assign an output field from outside. Exactly what, private members are invented for!!!

Comment: You can't return an error at compile time in such cases, but at runtime you can throw an exception  - if (!Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(LineNode).GetField(fieldName), typeof(Output))) throw new Exception(...);